# Why do area measurements from "measure area" tool and field calculator differ?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

My problem is when using the "measure Area" tool on the toolbar I get the correct value but when using the field calculator in the Layer Attributes the area is very different including -ve areas.  Both the project and layer are using a UTM CRS.
Using version 2.0.1

Comment: Could you add some more context? What software are you using? Maybe a link to a picture to demonstrate what you try to do could help as well.

Answer (score 1):

Note that identify tool and field calculators use different methods to calculate areas:

https://hub.qgis.org/issues/4252

```
Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Export/Add geometry columns
```

lets you choose if measurement of the new columns shall be in layer CRS, project CRS or ellipsodial (which the identify tool uses).