# Field Calculator returning incorrect length and area values when QGIS project is reopened

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, length

Similar to [Field Calculator returning incorrect length and area values](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76810/field-calculator-returning-incorrect-length-and-area-values), but as always slightly different.

I have QGIS 2.0 and when I create a polyline shapefile, the field calculator returns the correct lengths.  However the next time I open the project or the shapefile in a new workspace, when I click and the field calculator to update the line lengths, the numbers (in one instance) go to the 10,000,000's.

I have checked the project workspace it is in UTM Z51S and the units are in metres and the shapefile projection is the same.

I have updated the values to be zero first and then use $length to no avail.  I have even tried to changing the projection to WGS84 with units as metres and the values are in degrees.  It even happens when I create the values in a new field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rob - I had the same problem myself. The solution appears to be to turn off the project "on-the-fly" projection (Project > Project properties > CRS). The measurements come out correct once you do this. There was a similar problem in QGIS 1.7 and 1.8.

Rob